# Creating square buffer in qgis

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, buffer, analysis

How can I create a buffer with square ends along a line segment in qgis?

I've buffered lines using v.buffer in the GRASS plugin, but the -c option for square ends is not exposed in that interface.

Is there another way to do this with GRASS, or another tool?

Thanks!

update: I ended up using the grass qgis plugin with the "shell" module and just used the grass commands.  If you want to see the results in qgis you can use the "add grass vector layer" tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GRASS itself because it exposes the -c option.

Comment: Thanks!  I used this method, but with the grass plugin "shell" module so I wouldn't have to get into the grass application itself.  Do you know if there's a way to create individual features with v.buffer? (it seems to be grouping my features into larger ones in the output)

Comment: @zimmi I'm using GRASS itself, and have checked no caps, but still get them. Have you ever had this issue?

Answer (score 4):

- from [GRASS GIS: v.buffer](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.buffer.html):

> -c
>       Don't make caps at the ends of polylines

- from the interface of v.buffer.distance in QGIS (Processing Toolbox):

[image]

- from the interface of v.buffer.column in QGIS (Processing Toolbox):

[image]

or use GRASS GIS directly and not the GRASS plugin (as says zimmi)

Comment: Hi, do you know if its necessary to install anything besides the stock qgis application to see those tools?  I searched for "v.buffer.distance" in the grass plugin module list and processing toolbox search bar and can't find it.  Thanks!