# Using Grass to slightly smooth a polygon

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, geojson, features

I have a geojson file with a lot of features. Many of them look like that: 
[image: Feature]

What I'd like to get is a shape that very much resembles this one but is smoothed a little bit. Ideally, it would look similar to that one:

[image: result]

Do you have any ideas how to do this? I tried using GRASS in QGIS (generalize function) but I wasn't able to find parameters that would yield satisfactory results.

I used all of the algorithims available in GRASS v.generalize method using different parameters.

This is the GEOJson:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "shape",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": 
"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": 
"Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 70.297311693548977, 15.511449157884835 
], [ 70.297311693548977, 15.511457528420548 ], [ 70.297088479263266, 
15.511496590920549 ], [ 70.297094059620406, 15.511552394491977 ], [ 
70.297253099798979, 15.51153565342055 ], [ 70.297264260513259, 
15.511597037349121 ], [ 70.297311693548977, 15.511591456991978 ], [ 
70.297311693548977, 15.511588666813408 ], [ 70.297353546227555, 
15.511588666813408 ], [ 70.297353546227555, 15.511449157884835 ], [ 
70.297311693548977, 15.511449157884835 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

The most sensible soultion out of those included in v.generalize was to use chaiken method with small "Maximal tolerance value" parameter, but it was also not very good:

[image: chaiken]

Comment: The solutions listed there dint't yield a satisfactory result.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to show how you configured the tool, and explain why it wasn't satisfactory.

Comment: Edited, I hope now it tells the story

Comment: I fear what you want to do will be hard to set as it is. Try to think of a quantified criteria to erase a point and not another one. Smoothing generally gives you a rounded polygon.

Comment: [map shaper.org](http://mapshaper.org) is a site than import a GIS file, which then can be interactively generalized, then exported to a GIS file format of your choosing.

Comment: Did you try a simplifying algorithm? Chaiken is a smoothing algorithm which is not the same. @lynxlynxlynx highlights the potential pitfall of simplifying which is thin polygons.

Comment: I may finally have found a solution I didnt think of initially with square buffers (and grass v.buffer). See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to code this yourself, but I fear there is no way to always do it accurately. The chosen parameter(s) will just be off for some cases.

Two approaches come to mind:

- traversing the edges and deciding what to do at vertices depending on the running length and angle changes. Modify the geometry if they are small enough;
- computing the distance of consecutive vertices and if it is small enough, merging one into the other. For your example, maximising area would work as a way to decide which point to remove. This one is vulnerable to polygons thinner than the threshold though!

Answer (score 1):

You could try "square" buffering your layer by X distance (you'll have to try depending on your data) then by -X distance. It might be sufficient to remove little parts.

For that, you may be interested by the GRASS algorithm **v.buffer** with snap distance options activated. See [Creating square buffer in qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/creating-square-buffer-in-qgis)

I'll do some more tries to seek the best method to avoid round borders (the problem with my example below), but the main trick is to **use a square buffer method**.

[image: Buffer in and out]